# HMR / Hot Module Replacement problem with Vue.js 3 & webpack 5

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, webpack-hmr, vue-loader

I have a problem with webpack 5 and Vue.js 3 hot reloading - I don't know if some npm packages need updating (`vue-loader`?) or if I'm doing something wrong.

I created a minimal repository here:
https://github.com/dsine-de/vue3-webpack5

First time changes in `.vue` files work - but a second change just outputs a `Nothing changed` message (or stalls at `[WDS] App hot update...`, depending on the used `html-webpack-plugin` version).

Setting `cache: false` in webpack config seems to get rid of the problem.

I assume it's a bug in `vue-loader` because changes in entry `.js` file works (although with a full reload).

Answer (score 0):

Update webpack to version 4.0.0-beta.0